# is there any website to run ubuntu virtually

Tags: hard-drive, cloud

My hard disk is having health problems - "Disk failure is imminent".
Is there any website on which I can create an account and use ubuntu OS online?

Comment: I don't know, but it sounds like a great idea!

Comment: ...and how would you access that website without an OS running on some hardware?

Comment: dude, just boot a live-usb, or live-sd, or live-cd  also: you might unplug your hard drive while you wait to do data recovery. @mikewhatever hardrives aren't required... you could do it with PXE boot

Comment: ...and why would I need a website to "run Ubuntu virtually", even if I already have  running off a CD, ...dude? Forgive my doubting you, but that's a silly idea.

Comment: OF course you can get a cloud-hosting from Amazon etc. But how is it even going to solve your problem?! (btw, what is your problem?!) ;)

Comment: actually i do not have a cd or usb as for now and need to run os in a borrowed laptop.

Comment: Google has cloud hosting. So does Amazon.

Comment: @piratejp OK, let me get this straight , you are working right now from a borrowed laptop but do need Linux . . .if you need just the Linux terminal, then use [this](http://www.freelinuxconsole.info/terminal/) Login as `guest`.  Or [this](http://bellard.org/jslinux/) or [that](http://www.busybox.net/live_bbox/live_bbox.html). Option #2: emulators - cygwin, VirtualBox or VMWare . . .option #3, actually buy a USB and create an Ubuntu liveUSB; I *always* keep one or two around, in case of "oh sh*t" moments.

Answer (score 1):

If your hard disk has health problems : **replace the disk** !
Then you can use a service like [DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/).
(if that is what you really want...)

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible because if you don't have an os  then how you can access  a site or any thing.